# Empty foreach on one array alters another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've got an `$array1`. Then I create an `$array2` by `array_filter` of `$array1`. When I just iterate over `$array2` (empty loop) somehow an element duplicate is created and it replacing the existed element.

Here's the sample:

```
<?
    $array2 = array_filter($array1, function ($elem) use ($idsToExclude) {
        return in_array($elem["id"], $idsToExclude);
    });
?>

<?
    echo "== before iterating ==<br>";
        print_r($array1);
?>
    <? foreach ($array2 as $elem) :?>
        <!-- WRYYYYYYY! -->
    <? endforeach;?>
    <?
        echo "== after iterating ==<br>";
        print_r($array1);
?>
```

And the output:

```
== before ==
17 =>     Array (
    id => 1
    name => Test account 1
)
18 =>     Array (
    id => 102
    name => Test account 2
)
19 =>     Array (
    id => 37
    name => Test account 3
)
20 =>     Array (
    id => 82
    name => Test account 4
)
21 =>     Array (
    id => 97
    name => Test account 5
)

== after ==
17 =>     Array (
    id => 1
    name => Test account 1
)
18 =>     Array (
    id => 97
    name => Test account 5
)
19 =>     Array (
    id => 37
    name => Test account 3
)
20 =>     Array (
    id => 82
    name => Test account 4
)
21 =>     Array (
    id => 97
    name => Test account 5
)
```

Notice that in the second output `Test account 5` replaced `Test account 2`. If the `foreach` is commented, `$array1` don't being altered.

Comment: That's not very readable. Can you post the `print_r()` output of both the arrays (in `<pre>` tags, not inside any loop)?

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced: http://ideone.com/LR0W0x. However you have to keep in mind the notes and warnings from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: I came up with the same results as hindmost. [codepad.viper-7.com/sgcv1U](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sgcv1U). Couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @hindmost Thx for the link. You were 100% right: I didn't `unset` the reference in the `foreach ($array1 as &$elem)` I didn't put above. You can post an answer to this question and I'll accept it.

Comment: @efpies I can't post answer without any code (SO doesn't allow it). If you want to thank me, just upvote my latest answer (it can be found in my profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$array1` was created by the following code:

```php
foreach ($array1 as &$elem) {
    // Do something
}
```

Notice the `&` operator which allows to changee the original `$elem` in the loop (not its copy). Because the `&$elem` wasn't unset `after` the loop, the program suffered from undefined behaviour.

So the correct code will be

```php
foreach ($array1 as &$elem) {
    // Do something
}

unset($elem);
```